# Update old table data with new table data from different database

Tags: sql, sql-server

In this question, I will create a sample for you so you can understand what is my problem.

For example, I have 2 databases named **db1** and **db2**. Both databases have 1 table named **Stocks** since it is between old database and new database.

**db1's stock table**

```
StockCode | StockName |
   123    |   ChairA  |
   456    |   ChairB  |
   789    |   DeskA   |
   012    |   DeskB   |
```

**db2's stock table**

```
StockCode | StockName |
   abc    |   ChairAC |
   def    |   ChairBD |
   ghi    |   DeskAC  |
   jkl    |   DeskBD  |
```

I have tried this code below but it duplicate the stock name. I think this happen when I tried to join both table together and some new stocks in **db2** are not exist in **db1**. So to match the number of rows, it will duplicates the data.

**Here's the code**

```
SELECT 
   oldstock.StockCode as oldCode, 
   oldstock.StockName as oldName,
   newstock.StockCode as newCode, 
   newstock.StockName as newName
FROM [db1].[dbo].[Stocks] AS oldstock
INNER JOIN [db2].[dbo].[Stocks] AS newstock
ON oldstock.StockName LIKE '%'+newstock.StockName+'%'
ORDER BY StockCode ASC
```

Here's the original output:

[image: sql query output]

**For your information old db have 16389 items and new db have 16550 items which means new db have new stock item inserted.**

So the question is how to update **db1** with **db2** stock table data if only **db1** stockname contains in the **db2** stockname?

If the **db2** stock does not exist in **db1** stock, then do not insert the data to the **db1** stock table.

Here's the sample for you to try
[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b8ea1/1)

Comment: What is your actual issue ? Duplicate Data ?

Answer (score 1):

You may try placing your current inner join select query into a CTE, and then update that CTE:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 
        oldstock.StockCode as oldCode, 
        oldstock.StockName as oldName,
        newstock.StockCode as newCode, 
        newstock.StockName as newName
    FROM [db1].[dbo].[Stocks] AS oldstock
    INNER JOIN [db2].[dbo].[Stocks] AS newstock
        ON oldstock.StockName LIKE '%' + newstock.StockName + '%' AND
           oldstock.StockName <> newstock.StockName
)

UPDATE cte
SET
    oldCode = newCode,
    oldName = newName;
```

Comment: I got error messsage saying "Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.Stocks' with unique index 'IX_Stocks_StockCode'. The duplicate key value is (0488)". This happen because some of the stockname have similar names.

Comment: @Richmond Add another condition to the join which asserts that the two stock names are not completely identical.

Comment: I still got the same error message. In my table, some stockcode and stockname have identical values and some of it have been edited in my new database.

Comment: Then maybe you have a logical/business problem here.  If the new names/codes could already exist in the target column, then you would get this error.  I can't offer a workaround, because I don't know your data.

Comment: Is it possible to update old db without joining the new db? Because old db stock items might have less number of rows than the new db stock items. Would that affect the join function?

Comment: At this point, you should add sample data to your question which accurately represents the actual problem.

Comment: Please go to this link http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b8ea1/1 I have added the sql db there. You can try.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Join`

```
UPDATE db1
SET db1.oldCode = db2.newCode,    db1.oldName = db2.newName
FROM [db1].[dbo].[Stocks] AS db1 JOIN [db2].[dbo].[Stocks] AS db2
        ON db1.StockName LIKE '%' + db2.StockName + '%'
```

Comment: join both db will have duplicates of rows for both old and new db if stocks not exist

Comment: @Richmond Its based on your `ON` condition. You could've specify db1.StockName LIKE db2.StockName + '%'

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b8ea1/1 go to this link to try a sample.